# Is it possible to configure Visual Studio 2019 test project to discover test playlists in spesific folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, csproj, playlist

I am wondering if it is possible to configure Visual Studio 2019 test project to discover test playlists in specific folder ?

I have a project with a folder called `Playlists` and multiple `.playlist` files inside

Currently after each repository clone i have to open all my playlists one by one to have them loaded in visual studio.

[image]